# How to use PHP to recognising (and not validating) URL

Tags: php, url, protocols, strpos

I'm aware of `filter_var()` and it's `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` filter. The point is there are some URLs which are exist but not count as a valid URL and I need to verify them. For example, URLs with spaces.

At the moment I am checking only those protocols that application is interested in (http, https and ftp) using `strpos()`.

But I was wondering if there is a more generic method in PHP that I could employ?

It might help if i explain that i need to differentiate if the target source is a URL or a local path.

Comment: What is the difference between an invalid URL and an arbitrary string?

Comment: urls with spaces? WAT?

Comment: _URL WITH SPACES_ Really?

Comment: @Siguza, nothing my case is not to differentiate between a string and a URL. instead i need to indicate if my target is a URL or a local path. actually im going to add this to the main question

Comment: Can you provide examples showing us what is valid and what isn't?

Comment: try using regex according to your need..

Comment: Sure but please don't forget its not about validation. http://exampledomain.com/and some sub folder/and-the-file.html is the url while /User/myHome/path/to/a-file.txt or c:\path\to\another\file.txt are local paths. I'm looking for the best approach to distinguish them.

Comment: You could use file_exists() to check if the target exists. If it doesn't check if its a url.

Comment: @AnirbanN, at the moment I'm achieving the same using strpos(). somewhere i read its preferred  to getting involved with regex, performance wise :)

Comment: **Don't** use `regex`. A correct and complete `regex` that recognizes an URL is several hundreds characters long and most of the `regex`es you can find on the Internet for this purpose are either incomplete or simply wrong. The simplest way to recognize an URL is to parse it into pieces (better use function `parse_url()` for that) and then analyze each piece (with `regex` if you like) against its own rules (e.g. the scheme against a list of allowed schemes, the hostname part looks like a hostname or a valid IP address, the port, if present, is numeric a.s.o)

Comment: You could make sure you've got a file rather than an url by making sure `allow_url_fopen` is switched off and then use `file_exists()` ... of course, if the file doesn't exist it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the URL into components then do some basic analysis on the pieces it returns (or just check if the returned value is an `array()` or `FALSE`).

As the documentation says:

> This function is not meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts. Partial URLs are also accepted, `parse_url()` tries its best to parse them correctly.

And also:

> On seriously malformed URLs, `parse_url()` may return `FALSE`.

It looks like it matches your request pretty well.